# <h1> <h2> seo link tag

Tags: hyperlink, h2

```
i know <h2>Hamburger</h2> are good, but how about this:

<div><h2><a href="/food.html">Food</a> » Hamburger</h2></div>
```

or thats are ok for google seo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  tag with an anchor link inside it will work same as a normal  tag for Google SEO. Both the methods are Ok, but the problem that can occur is your readers may go away because you added a hyperlink in the Heading text of your webpage. So, it is not a good practice to use hyperlinks in  tags or any  tag.